# Is there anyway to determine how much more ram my prog can allocate till OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, out-of-memory, ram

I need this to determine if I can load file fully to RAM with File.ReadAllBytes (fast) or process file with parts via FileStream, by reading the amount of bytes close to OutOfMemoryException, but enough to avoid it.

I do this to reduce HDD load. I think is better to read 1gb at once, than do read cycles like: read 4 bytes -> process those -> read 4 bytes again -> process those -> ...

Comment: You tend not to be able to because the memory is an OS concern. Have you tried looking into [Memory Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx)?

Comment: Thank you for this. I didn't knew those exist in c#. I was using .net 2.0 and those are new in .net 4.0. But I don't know how fast the access to it... Not only speed, but also HDD read cycles should be optimal, instead of reading some other files and always moving from my file to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory allocation depends on how much load their currently is. You cannot pick a number and hope you will be able to allocate that much space always. You should pick a safe number that has low chance of failure. Streams usually use 1-8MB buffers I suppose.

HDD load would be more or less same when reading 1Gb at once and reading it in chunk of 256MB 4 times. In the end: you are reading 1GB.